# VendorOption parameters (graphic-margin,...) based on attribute

Tags: geoserver, polygon, sld, fill

I want to add margins around polygon graphic fills based on an attribute but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong or maybe it's not possible at all. 
The same goes for other VendorOption parameters.

This works:

```
<VendorOption name="graphic-margin">10</VendorOption>
```

This does not work:

```
<VendorOption name="graphic-margin">
  <ogc:PropertyName>usuaris</ogc:PropertyName>
</VendorOption>
```

Nor this:

```
<VendorOption name="graphic-margin">
  <ogc:Div>
    <ogc:PropertyName>usuaris</ogc:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Literal>50</ogc:Literal>
  </ogc:Div>  
</VendorOption>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vendor options can only use static values.

If you are interested in sponsoring attribute dependence support you should follow this process:

https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-new-features-and-improvements-in-GeoServer